# Getting error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot open an already opened ItemReader, call close first

Tags: spring-batch

2021-07-15 17:40:41.004 ERROR 76282 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step randoms in job ETL-Loads

org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:410) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:192) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.athenahealth.pms.Application.main(Application.java:24) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot open an already opened ItemReader, call close first
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doOpen(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:135) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
... 36 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot open an already opened ItemReader, call close first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes cause spring-batch will itself initiate batch operation on first load.So its required to add spring.batch.job.enabled=false in properties file.